# Pairing iBeacon silently

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ibeacon

I'd like to know if there's a way (with public or private API) to pair my device with an iBeacon silently (without having to input the pincode manually).

Or if you know if there's an iBeacon device out in the market that does not include a pincode to pair with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Pairing is not at all a requirement for iBeacons. What are you using as an iBeacon? For the time being, either you are using an iOS device to broadcast as an iBeacon or you are using a 3rd party device that broadcasts the iBeacon profile.

[This iBeacon demo](https://github.com/csmann/iBeaconDemo) on GitHub will be a good place to see iBeacons broadcaster/client (both iOS devices) connecting (without passcodes, of course).

If you are looking for 3rd party iBeacons, [Estimotes](http://estimote.com/) are seem to be the best route.

Comment: Well, the iBeacon I got needs a pincode in order to modify its UUID, major and minor, which I need to modify for my implementation since I'm going to use iBeacons in a large scale and can't afford to waste time remembering pincodes. And yes, I'm using and need third party devices to act as iBeacons. I'll take a look to the example and Estimotes, thanks!

Comment: Sounds good.  It sounds like your device needs to be paired to so you can modify it then (as opposed to "programming" it via a hard wire). Interesting.  Keep in mind when you use them in production, they should *never* need to be paired to by anyone.